# date_default_timezone_set("timezone") and mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp

i have set the timezone to any time zone  that the user have 
for example  `"America/New_York"`

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

then i make the flowing statements

```
$data =mysql_query("SELECT DATE FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 2");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($data);

echo date("H:i:s",strtotime($row['data')));
```

the DATE column store date in GMT timezone .. i want to display the equivalent date in

ANY TIME ZONE the user prefer

what is wrong , maybe i am wrong @ something

any help please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note my changes...

```
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime($row['data']) + date('Z')); // date('Z') returns timezone offset in seconds
```

Comment: i want to set any timezone as the user prefer ... not new work all the time

Comment: Note my edit - `date()` uses `Z` to determine timezone offset from GMT based on what is currently set as your default timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your timezone-table enabled:

```
 mysql_query("SET time_zone='EST';");
 $data =mysql_query("SELECT DATE FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 2");
 //...etc.
```

If you haven't:

```
 mysql_query("SET time_zone='-05:00';");
 $data =mysql_query("SELECT DATE FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 2");
 //...etc.
```